# Android Layout xml - eclipse

Tags: android-layout, expander

sorry for my question, but I'm android beginner :-)
I need help just with create layout, some best practices for my solution.
My requested layout must be on the screen splitted to 3 parts:

1. header as expander - if possible

   - fix size (height 200px / width fill) of the screen - if expanded
   - linear layout - horizontal with 3 rows of labels
   - only first label is visible if expander is collapsed
   - top of screen
2. body

   - dynamically resize (height fill place between header and footer / width fill)
   - scrollable vertical
   - horizontal will change body with another (not necessary now)
   - in body will be two level list - headers as parent, expandable to child
3. List item

   - fix size (height 200px / width fill) of the screen
   - linear layout - vertical (with 4 images icons)
   - bottom of screen

My basic problem is how create basic layout (header / body / footer) as panels in whitch I can add next controls.
Create it as linear layout?? How correct fix it on the screen? What header as expander?

Comment: Elaborate `expander`. What is it? A Spinner?

Comment: I know expander from wpf - http://arcanecode.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/wpf052-thumb.jpg?w=323&h=180

Comment: There's no such a thing in Android.

Comment: OK, so will be need change layout property from code.. Right, expander is not necessary now. I will add button into the header for change header height, probably...

Comment: Or you can make a custom expandable View. But, if you expand the header, the body must be shrunk...